# Nine-patch scaling on Android

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a 9-patch that goes like this:

[image]

I'm using it as a background for a rectangular area in an Android app. I expect that the center pixel takes the majority of the area, the pixel right above is scaled to a one pixel thick horizontal line underneath the frame, the one to the left forms a one pixel thick vertical line, and so forth. All the 9-patch guides state that.

However, users are reporting color artifacts on display, as if those pixels are scaled in the other direction, too:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have 9-patch files for every density? or just one 9-patch file placed in drawable / drawable-mdpi / whatever ?

Comment: Just one file in drawable.

Comment: thats why... you could of course place it in `drawable-nodpi` (which prevents any density scaling) but i'm not sure if it is what you really want

Comment: The slightly lighter shade of gray above the label takes about as much space as the label - on the order of 50px. What kind of density factor is this???

Comment: this is because your one physical pixel is "prescaled" so after that it is like virtual pixel with top half in one color and bottom half in another - just prepare your 9patches for mdpi / hdpi / xhdpi to avoid that

Comment: Do you mean, it first scales the center rect by the density factor, *then* applies the stretching logic? Looks like that. Thank you.

Comment: yep its exactly like that  - but if you really need just one 9patch its better to use xdpi version since downscaling looks better that upscaling